# DDL object exist check

Tags: flyway

When I running DDL using flyway it break if Object already exist because some one executed script already.

Do we have a way in FlyWayDB while running DDL that can check if object exist or not.

to avoid error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the information schema of your database and decide accordingly. But in practice this will rarely (probably never) be needed if you stick to a clean Flyway workflow where are schema changes are applied through Flyway migrations.

Comment: make sense but in lower lifecycles we using flyway db to run release scripts at once to keep them in sync but team members some time execute